# Using CSS to set scrollbar Width

Tags: html, css

I am adding the following CSS style to set the scroll bar width in my DIV element. 
My question is in some part of the div tag of the same page, the width is adjusted but in other part, the div tag is wrong.

Can you please tell me if I do this, if that mean I am setting the scroll bar globally in my whole page. Is this correct?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 24px;
}
```

Comment: can You add a snippet?

Comment: What you have posted should set the scroll bars globally (in webkit browsers).

Answer (score 0):

This sets the scrollbar width:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;   // for vertical scroll bar
  height: 8px;  // for horizontal scroll bar
}

// for Firefox add this class as well
.thin_scroll{
  scrollbar-width: thin; // auto | thin | none | <length>;
}
```